# Subsetting a data frame by specifying a vector of length >1 for a variable

Tags: r

I just started learning R programming, and I found a problem subsetting a data frame with the following variables:

```
> names(data)

[1] "Date"    "sulfate" "nitrate" "ID"
```

To get the mean of one variable I just use:

> mean(data$sulfate)

```
[1] 3.880701
```

If i want the mean of the variable "sulcate" when variable "ID" is 1 I use:

> mean(subset(data, ID==1)$sulfate)
>
> [1] 3.004444

However if I want the mean of "sulcate" when ID is a range 1:5 I get the error:

> mean(subset(data, ID==1:5)$sulfate)
>
> [1] 3.714615
>       Warning message:
>       In ID == 1:5 :
>         longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>
> How can I specify a vector of length > 1 (i.e. 1:10, 5:8) in order to filter a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `%in%` instead of `==`

```
mean(subset(data, ID %in% 1:5)$sulfate)
```

or perhaps:

```
mean(data$sulfate[data$ID %in% 1:5])
```

That warning means that when `1:5` was extended to the length of `data$ID`, it was not recycled an integral number of times.  A worse result would be if the number of rows were divisible by 5.  In that case, wrong results would be silently returned.